# Add Ant script lines to Eclipse build procedure

Tags: eclipse, ant

I'm making java project using eclipse. I suppose that Eclipse is using Ant to build project. Now I need to create jar file and to copy it over ftp. I need add few lines in Ant script file, but can't find where it is. What is the name of projects build script file?

Comment: "build.xml" and Eclipse must be configured to use ANT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't use Ant for building projects, at least not by default. However, you can add a new Ant Builder to your project, to make it execute an Ant build script each time the project is built: open the properties of your Java project, then select "Builders", click on "New", then select "Ant Builder" and click "OK", as in this screen capture:
[image: new Ant Builder]

In the next dialog, conifgure the Ant script and target you want to use to jar your project, and you're done. The jar will be built from your Ant script each time the Eclipse project is built or re-built.